# Using gawk Sum total last column and append sum exactly to the end of last column maintaining the formatting - preferred inplace edit

Tags: bash, awk

Inplace editing preferred
Convert size column conditionally and append total to last column end
Data:
Columns:

```
"File_Name","Owner","Mod","Size"
```

```
"1","A",","mp4","369.775MB"
"2","B","mp4","363.806MB"
"3","C","txt","441.835MB"
"4","D","pdf","373.809MB"
"5","U","ps","363.845MB"
"6","E","svg","34MB"
"7","F","mkv","408GB"
"8","G","log","3KB"
"9","H","log","34KB"
"10","I","log","39KB"
```

FOR $NF.
Expected output:

```
"1","A",","mp4","369.775MB"
"2","B","mp4","363.806MB"
"3","C","txt","441.835MB"
"4","D","pdf","373.809MB"
"5","U","ps","363.845MB"
"6","E","svg","34MB"
"7","F","mkv","408GB"
"8","G","log","3KB"
"9","H","log","34KB"
"10","I","log","39KB" 
               Total:"409.92GB"
```

```
BEGIN {
OFS=FS=","
}
{
if ($NF~/GB/) {gsub(/"/, "", $NF); sum+=($NF*1024*1024*1024); gsub(/.*/,"\"&\"",$NF)}; 
if ($NF~/MB/) {gsub(/"/, "", $NF);sum+=($NF*1024*1024); gsub(/.*/,"\"&\"",$NF)}; 
if ($NF~/KB/) {gsub(/"/, "", $NF);sum+=($NF*1024); gsub(/.*/,"\"&\"",$NF)} } 
END {
if (sum >= 1099511627776) { sum=sum/1024/1024/1024/1024; gsub(/.*/, "&TB", sum) }; 
if (sum >= 1073741824 && sum < 1099511627776) { sum=sum/1024/1024/1024; gsub(/.*/, "&GB", sum) }; 
if (sum < 1073741824 && sum >= 1048576) {sum=sum/1024/1024; gsub(/.*/, "&MB", sum)}; 
if (sum < 1048576) {sum=sum/1024; gsub(/.*/, "&KB", sum)1} print "Total: \""sum"\""
}1
```

Above code works to get desired sum.

But how to print the sum exactly at end of last row aligning properly like pretty print table.

Logic 1) Get length of all lines and average

```
BEGIN { 
FS=","
OFS=FS
}
{
len+=(length)
if ($NF~/GB/) {gsub(/"/, "", $NF); sum+=($NF*1024*1024*1024); gsub(/.*/,"\"&\"",$NF)}; 
if ($NF~/MB/) {gsub(/"/, "", $NF);sum+=($NF*1024*1024); gsub(/.*/,"\"&\"",$NF)}; 
if ($NF~/KB/) {gsub(/"/, "", $NF);sum+=($NF*1024); gsub(/.*/,"\"&\"",$NF)} } 
END {
len=int(len/NR+1)
if (sum >= 1099511627776) { sum=sum/1024/1024/1024/1024; gsub(/.*/, "&TB", sum) }; 
if (sum >= 1073741824 && sum < 1099511627776) { sum=sum/1024/1024/1024; gsub(/.*/, "&GB", sum) }; 
if (sum < 1073741824 && sum >= 1048576) {sum=sum/1024/1024; gsub(/.*/, "&MB", sum)}; 
if (sum < 1048576) {sum=sum/1024; gsub(/.*/, "&KB", sum)1} 
printf "%*s:\"\n", len, "Total:" "\""sum"\""
}1
```

Logic 2) Get length of all lines and average -
Also  Sorting  the file from longest line to shortest to opimise the output

```
BEGIN { 
FS=","
OFS=FS
}
{
f = length
m[f] = m[f] ? m[f] RS $0 : $0
len+=(length)
if ($NF~/GB/) {gsub(/"/, "", $NF); sum+=($NF*1024*1024*1024); gsub(/.*/,"\"&\"",$NF)}; 
if ($NF~/MB/) {gsub(/"/, "", $NF);sum+=($NF*1024*1024); gsub(/.*/,"\"&\"",$NF)}; 
if ($NF~/KB/) {gsub(/"/, "", $NF);sum+=($NF*1024); gsub(/.*/,"\"&\"",$NF)} } 
END {
len=int(len/NR+1)
if (sum >= 1099511627776) { sum=sum/1024/1024/1024/1024; gsub(/.*/, "&TB", sum) }; 
if (sum >= 1073741824 && sum < 1099511627776) { sum=sum/1024/1024/1024; gsub(/.*/, "&GB", sum) }; 
if (sum < 1073741824 && sum >= 1048576) {sum=sum/1024/1024; gsub(/.*/, "&MB", sum)}; 
if (sum < 1048576) {sum=sum/1024; gsub(/.*/, "&KB", sum)1} 
for (f in m) q[++x] = m[f]
while (x) print q[x--]
printf "%*s:\"\n", len, "Total:" "\""sum"\""
}
```

Logic 3) Get most frequent line length and then use it

Logic 4) Use last line length upto double quotes and print that much space before priting total
This way total will align to last field of last record.

As shown in
https://stackoverflow.com/a/71196580/18057019

Other logic for pretty print like results are invited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `awk` idea:

```
awk -F'"' '                                # input field delimiter == double quote
BEGIN { kb=1024
        mb=kb*kb
        gb=mb*kb
        tb=gb*kb

        factors[""]=1
        factors["KB"]=kb
        factors["MB"]=mb
        factors["GB"]=gb
        factors["TB"]=tb

        sum=0
      }
      { print

        value=unit=toupper( $(NF-1) )      # make copies of $(NF-1) and ...
        gsub(/KB|MB|GB/,"",value)          # strip off unit to get value
        gsub(/[-.0-9]/,"",unit)            # strip off number to get unit

        sum+= (value * factors[unit])
      }
END   {      if (sum >= tb) unit="TB"
        else if (sum >= gb) unit="GB"
        else if (sum >= mb) unit="MB"
        else if (sum >= kb) unit="KB"
        else                unit=""

        # using OPs 3rd definition of "alignment":
        #
        #     Use last line length upto " and print that much space
        #     before printing total. This way total will align to last
        #     field of last record
        #
        # use regex to define start of last comma-delimited field;
        # use match() to find start position of regex and add offset
        # for string "Total"; store value in "x" variable; feed "x"
        # to "printf"; if "x=17" then format string "%*s" becomes "%17s"

        regex=",[^,]*$"
        x=match($0,regex) + 5

        printf "%*s:\"%.3f%s\"\n", x, "Total", (sum/factors[unit]), unit
      }
' raw.dat
```

This generates:

```
"1","A",","mp4","369.775MB"
"2","B","mp4","363.806MB"
"3","C","txt","441.835MB"
"4","D","pdf","373.809MB"
"5","U","ps","363.845MB"
"6","E","svg","34MB"
"7","F","mkv","408GB"
"8","G","log","3KB"
"9","H","log","34KB"
"10","I","log","39KB"
               Total:"409.902GB"
```

Comment: ok, that's a 4th way to define 'align' ... just pick whatever you want and modify `x` accordingly

Comment: you've already modified the original question/requirement several times; I suggest asking a new question making sure to provide sample inputs, the code you've attempted, the (wrong) results generated by your code, and the (correct) expected results